# Need help with Wishlist

Tags: magento

The wishlist section in the sidebar disappears when all the items in it are removed.. but i want to shot it even when there is no items in wishlist with a text "Add some items to your wishlist".. as like "Compare section".. how do i do it?

i tried editing the .phtml file for doing it, but its not working.. do i need to edit any xml layout file for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*For just info, please don't reputate.*

The wishlist class has been changed after 1.4.2 :

```
* @deprecated after 1.4.2.0
     * @see Mage_Wishlist_Block_Links::__construct
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function addWishlistLink()
    {
        return $this;
    }
```

and here is the your requested feature ( look at count ) :

```
/**
     * Add link on wishlist page in parent block
     *
     * @return Mage_Wishlist_Block_Links
     */
    public function addWishlistLink()
    {
        $parentBlock = $this->getParentBlock();
        if ($parentBlock && $this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) {
            $count = $this->helper('wishlist')->getItemCount();
            if ($count > 1) {
                $text = $this->__('My Wishlist (%d items)', $count);
            }
            else if ($count == 1) {
                $text = $this->__('My Wishlist (%d item)', $count);
            }
            else {
                $text = $this->__('My Wishlist');
            }
            $parentBlock->addLink($text, 'wishlist', $text, true, array(), 30, null, 'class="top-link-wishlist"');
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Magento 1.6.1.0

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/Block/Customer/Sidebar.php
```

contains the function **_toHtml()**:

```
protected function _toHtml()
{
    if (($this->getCustomWishlist() && $this->getItemCount()) || $this->hasWishlistItems()) {
        return parent::_toHtml();
    }

    return '';
}
```

Copy:

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/Block/Customer/Sidebar.php
```

to:

```
/app/code/local/Mage/Wishlist/Block/Customer/Sidebar.php
```

In the copied file, replace the contents of function _toHtml() with return parent::_toHtml();:

```
protected function _toHtml()
{
        return parent::_toHtml();
}
```